# Gallery items overlapping (bleed in)

Tags: android, gallery

My probel is that images in my Gallery are bleeding in into each other once I begin scrolling towards the next image.

I am using a `android.widget.Gallery` connected to a custom adapter I extended from `BaseAdapter`.

The adapter's GetView() method is like this

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
            if (mImageBitmap != null && position < mImageBitmap.length)
             i.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap[position]);
            return i;
```

[image]
            }

Comment: Why are you setting the image bitmap yourself, instead of letting the adapter take care of it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually found the solution to my problem. In getView(), the ImageView I was returning had no background and thus the ImageViews would overlap. I set the background of the ImageView to black before returning it and it looks great

Answer (score 29):

Did you try using android:spacing ( in xml) or setSpacing(int spacing) (in code) on the Gallery?

Comment: This did the trick for me. The overlap of gallery items started when I started inflating the items from an xml. Now that is solved - thanks!

Comment: Worked for me too: setSpacing(0)

Comment: Worked, don't forget to set the units: setSpacing(0dp)

Answer (score 3):

It seems the fading is added automatically and disabling through XML doesn't work.

However disabling programatically seems to work:

Gallery carousel = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.image_carousel);
carousel.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Gallery instance, you can also call the following method to remove the bleed in area:

```
gallery.setUnselectedAlpha(1.0f);
```

This also removes the white-ish haziness of the Gallery view.